# Multiple Image Upload with previews each

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i am currently creating an image upload page where you can upload images one by one by each requirement. Currently it works with one preview..
How can i add another input type file where the image preview is separate from the first one? I did try it but it just replaces the past preview..

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

//first one
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<span name = "preview1" id ="preview1"></span>
//second one
<input type="file2" name="file" id="file2" />
<span name = "preview2" id ="preview2"></span>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function filePreview(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#preview1 + img').remove();
        $('#preview1').after('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="450" height="300"/>');
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
    $("#file").change(function () {
   filePreview(this);
});
</script>
```

Comment: In much the same way that we have absolute and relative file-paths and urls, you can have absolute and relative references to html elements. You've gone with the absolute method, but will need the relative approach. You'll need to understand the use of `this` in event-handlers.

Comment: @enhzflep You are right! i forgot about that thanks for that catch! you can add that as an answer if you want.. Thanks again!

Comment: how is this a php related question?

Comment: sorry added by mistake -removed tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems in your code are in your css selectors.

`$('#preview1 + img').remove();`

You're removing the adjacent sibling `<img>` element **directly** after the element with id `preview1`.

`$('#preview1').after(...)`

And here you're inserting the new `<img>` element directly after the first file input (#preview1).

What you could do is using your function argument `this` (which refers to the right file input element, the one on which the `change` event fired).

Since you're already using jquery you could use the methods [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [after](https://api.jquery.com/after/) in conjunction with your function argument `input`.

Here is your `filePreview` function reworked :

```
function filePreview(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(input).next('img').remove();
            $(input).after('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="450" height="300"/>');
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Yep it did thanks, after what @enhzflep said my mistake i got it and you made it even better. After copying your new function I just made different  $("#file").change(function () in each one. Thanks!